# Why "for 700 zuz"?

Tags: bava-metzia

The ninth chapter of *mishnayos Bava M'tzia* had numerous cases in which someone is working someone else's field, whether as part of a sharecropping agreement or under lease. Most of them do not indicate the price. Some do so so as to indicate that the agreement was for a fixed price rather than a percentage. And then there's *mishna* 10, which lists a price for no apparent reason:

> הַמְקַבֵּל שָׂדֶה מֵחֲבֵרוֹ לְשָׁבוּעַ אֶחָד בִּשְׁבַע מֵאוֹת זוּז הַשְּׁבִיעִית מִן הַמִּנְיָן. קִבְּלָהּ הֵימֶנּוּ שֶׁבַע שָׁנִים בִּשְׁבַע מֵאוֹת זוּז אֵין הַשְּׁבִיעִית מִן הַמִּנְיָן.
>
> Someone who [rents] a field from his fellow for a septennial (one shmitah cycle) for seven hundred *zuz*, the *sh'mita* year is included in the count. If he got it from him for seven years for seven hundred *zuz*, the *sh'mita* year is excluded from the count.

Why does it mention the price?

Comment: Maybe because the stam daas changes when the number is a nice multiple of 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Art Scroll Gemora Daf 110b2 notes 22 and 23 explains the specific usage of 700 zuz (I do not have the Art Scroll Mishnayos which would also have this note). The reason for the specification of the amount is to show that the fee is fixed for the entire period specified rather than as a rent of 100 *zuz* per year. This makes it easier for the Mishnah to show the difference rather than using the term *a fixed fee*.

> **22** The landowner need not leave the land in the renter's possession for another year to compensate for the *sheviis* year, when
>   the tenant was not allowed to work on the field and profit from it.
>   Furthermore, since the rental agreement fixed the seven hundred *zuz*
>   fee for one septennial, rather than seven years, the owner need not
>   deduct a seventh of the rental for the *sheviis* year even though the
>   tenant cannot till the field that year (see *Nemukei Yosef*)
>
> The Mishnah uses the example of a rental fee of seven hundred *zuz* to
>   teach that there is no implication that the fee was based on a
>   calculation of one hundred *zuz* per year. Rather the seven hundred
>   *zuz* was the fee for the entire period, which is understood to include only six working years (*Toras Chaim*; see also *Kos Ha
>   Yeshuos*)
>
> **23** If the rental agreement stipulated "seven years" [rather than one septennial], the implication is that the lease is for seven
>   working years. Therefore the owner must leave the field in the
>   tenant's possession for an additional year in lieu of the *sheviis*
>   year when he could not work. (see *Meiri*)